Remove linter warning for unused `export default function DummyPage` when using `expo-router`
import React from 'react';

[... code ...]

export default function DummyPage(): React.JSX.Element {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ "Unused default export"
  [... code ...]
}

How can I get rid of this ("Unused default export") linter warning??

My IDE is Rider from JetBrains

The expo-router has no problem navigating to this page, but the linter warning is something I would like to not see (though it is true, there are 0 code references to this function, at least in the code I've written)
I have also tried:
[... code ...]

function DummyPage(): React.JSX.Element {
  [... code ...]
}

export default DummyPage;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ "Unused default function"


This DummyPage is navigated to via:
router.navigate('main/menu/DummyPage');

To be clear, this is only a linting issue that is bothering me, the code still works and navigation functions as expected.
Any information or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I came across the answer in Rider by hovering over the suggestion context menu that Rider provides for the function DummyPage: Remove unused default export > Suppress for statement

Which produces:
import React from 'react';

[... code ...]

// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
export default function DummyPage(): React.JSX.Element {
  [... code ...]
}

With the above comment, the warning goes away :)

After discovering this, and Googling "typescript noinspection", I was able to find several StackOverflow answers regarding this topic. For instance, the top result answers (#1 & #2) cover this solution as well.
The second answer (#2, the accepted answer) also includes a direct link to WebStorm's (analogous to Rider) documentation for Disabling and enabling inspections
